# How to show this is commutative and participative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is the question:

Suppose that the mathematical structure $(S,*)$ has an inert member. Show that if the following relation holds for any 4 arbitrary members $a, b, c, d$ of $S$, then the combination rule $*$ is commutative and participative.
$$(a*b) * (c*d) = (a*c) * (b*d)$$

But I haven't got any idea.

Here's my solution:

To show that the combination rule $*$ is commutative, we need to show that $a*b = b*a$ for all $a, b \in S$.

To show that $*$ is participative, we need to show that $(a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$ for all $a, b, c \in S$.

First, let's consider the special case where $a$ is the inert element. Since the inert element is an identity element with respect to the combination rule $*$, we have $a*b = b$ and $b*a = a$ for all $b \in S$.

Therefore, if the given relation holds for any 4 arbitrary members $a, b, c, d$ of $S$, then it must hold for $a = e$, where $e$ is the inert element.

If we substitute $a = e$ into the given relation, we get
\begin{align*} (e*b) * (c*d) &= (e*c) * (b*d) \ b * (c*d) &= c * (b*d) \ b*c*d &= c*b*d. \end{align*}
for all $b, c, d \in S$.

This is the last thing I wrote about it. But I don't know if it's true so I can continue or my way is wrong.

Comment: Letting different variables in the equation given for the property is definitely the right way to go, you're on the right track, but I don't think your exact choice will be fruitful. Try to work backwards a little: pick which property you want to prove, and select elements to set equal to the identity according to what will give you those identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a=e$ and $d=e$, then $b*c=(e*b)*(c*e)=(a*b)*(c*d)=(a*c)*(b*d)=c*b$, so we have commutativity. For associativity, we take $(a*b)*d=(a*b)*(e*d)=(a*e)*(b*d)=a*(b*d)$.